# How to create an add-in that does not appear on the ribbon

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, ribbonx

I am trying to develop an add-in that activates when composing a message. However, I do not want the add-in to appear on the ribbon. Instead, I want it to appear right above the "Send" and "To" buttons. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No, Outlook web add-ins don't provide anything for that.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: I can confirm that this is the correct place to direct new feature requestions. Thanks for the quick answer Eugene!